# How to prevent user from executing js function in console

Tags: javascript

Is there anything I can do to prevent users to run js function which is in file from console ? I have this `getReward` function here:

```
    function getReward(){

    $('.reward-button').remove();
    $('#rewardBtn').remove();

    document.getElementById("fightInfo").innerHTML = 

    '<strong>You</strong> won the fight.<br><strong>Reward:</strong><br>Gold: ' +gold+' <img src="/img/gold.png" style="margin-top: -1%"><br>EXP: '+exp+'<br>'
    +
    '<br>'
    +
    '<button style="font-size: 24px;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="backToArena();">⚔️<br>Back To Arena</button>';

    socket.emit('win-fight', {
        gold: gold,
        exp: exp,
        username: userName,
        enemyname: enemyName
    });   

}

    function backToArena(){
        window.location.href = "/arena";
    }
```

The problem is that user can just type in console `getReward();` and he automatically get's the reward because then socket works and it goes to server side from client side. Is there anyway to prevent this ?

UPDATE

```
 document.getElementById("rewardBtn").innerHTML = 
    '<button style="background-color: blue; font-size: 24px;" class="btn btn-primary" id="reward-button">Get reward </button>';
```

And then I do this:

```
document.querySelector('#reward-button').addEventListener('click', getReward);
```

But this doesn't run getReward function nothing happens no error.

Comment: I know this comment will not answer your question, but given your architecture and implementation, is it to implement the winning logic on the backend side. This way you could export the getReward() logic to a place where the user has no chanc of triggering the rewarding process.

Comment: Any and all client side code is insecure. You can intercept all JavaScript and run it in the console. You can even write your own code to run against the page. You can obscure the code but not make it impossible to execute in dev tools. Web Assembly might be an a possible option but i dare say any features implemented with it can can still be executed through JS so probably wont make any difference. (Not looked into web assembly enough yet.)

Comment: Even if you somehow manage to prevent console usage, users can still run js bookmarklets for the same effect

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the whole script in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) so that `getReward` (and all your other functions) are not on the top level. Functions (and other variables) on the top level are automatically assigned to `window`, and are thus callable by simply typing the function name into the console. But, if a function is declared *inside another function*, the inner function won't be assigned to the global object.

```
(() => {
  function getReward(){

    $('.reward-button').remove();
    $('#rewardBtn').remove();

    document.getElementById("fightInfo").innerHTML = 

      '<strong>You</strong> won the fight.<br><strong>Reward:</strong><br>Gold: ' +gold+' <img src="/img/gold.png" style="margin-top: -1%"><br>EXP: '+exp+'<br>'
      +
      '<br>'
      +
      '<button style="font-size: 24px;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="backToArena();">⚔️<br>Back To Arena</button>';

    socket.emit('win-fight', {
      gold: gold,
      exp: exp,
      username: userName,
      enemyname: enemyName
    });   

  }

  function backToArena(){
    window.location.href = "/arena";
  }
})();
```

Wrapping your scripts in an IIFE is useful not only for security (not *good* security, but better than *open-console-and-type-function* insecurity), but also for the sake of avoiding pollution of the global namespace, which is best avoided when possible.

Comment: That makes it slightly less trivial for the user, but it still isn't hard to cheat.

Comment: Okay but now when I click the button for the reward it says that function `getReward` is not defined

Comment: @abraom_185 Sounds like you're using inline attribute handlers, which are not a good idea - assign the listener with Javascript instead, inside the IIFE.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So it would be good idea to run this function 
inside `$(button).on('click', function(){});` ?

Comment: @abraom_185 Sure, but there's no need to import a big library like jQuery just to attach a listener, you can use `addEventListener`, for example, `document.querySelector('<yourbuttonselector>').addEventListener('click', getReward);`

Comment: It seems that I can't run function when button appears as innerHTML with it's own id

Comment: @abraom_185 It's not clear what your problem is, any element that's selectable can have a listener attached to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181730/discussion-between-abraom-185-and-certainperformance).

Comment: Great content apart from the security point. It makes Zero different from a security stand point where a person is physically trying to compromise a site. With Chrome's new search feature you can search every single file loaded in the browser for content so would make finding the obfuscated code even easier now.

Comment: With the solution provided by @CertainPerformance, you can integrate it with a JS Obfuscator tool to make it more difficult to understand your code

Answer (score 0):

here is **magic**

```js
"use strict";
!function() {
  function detectDevTool(allow) {
    if(isNaN(+allow)) allow = 100;
    var start = +new Date();
    debugger;
    var end = +new Date();
    if(isNaN(start) || isNaN(end) || end - start > allow) {
      consoleCheck();
    }
  }
  if(window.attachEvent)
  {
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive")
    {
      detectDevTool();
      window.attachEvent('onresize', detectDevTool);
      window.attachEvent('onmousemove', detectDevTool);
      window.attachEvent('onfocus', detectDevTool);
      window.attachEvent('onblur', detectDevTool);
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout(argument.callee, 0);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    window.addEventListener('load', detectDevTool);
    window.addEventListener('resize', detectDevTool);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', detectDevTool);
    window.addEventListener('focus', detectDevTool);
    window.addEventListener('blur', detectDevTool);
  }
}();

function consoleCheck()
{
  document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = 'We strongly support to not using console for extra actions!';
}
```

Just add this script in your project it will definitely stops inspecting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you have the console open before loading, you can still see the console and execute function.

Comment: Hello @saf1 you can try out above code hope this could helps you and other community.